# Improving collision detection in a simple Javascript block buster game

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

So I have a simple block buster game (Player controls paddle to bounce ball that is supposed to hit and destroy game blocks, simple stuff).

It's more or less done, but I'm looking for ways to improve the collision detection I have in place.

The collision detection I'm using works well enough most of the time, but sometimes when the ball hits corners of the blocks, the collision detection works unpredictably and I'm trying to get rid of that behaviour.

This is basically how my collision detection determines which direction the ball needs to bounce to:

```
                    if (xdistancefromcenter < ydistancefromcenter)
                    {
                        dy = -dy;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dx = -dx;
                    }
```

dx and dy are variables for the ball's speed and x/y distancefromcenter is calculated earlier in the function to determine the ball's x and y distances from the center of the block it's colliding with

It's very simple and I tried replacing this with a more complex solution by considering which directions the ball is approaching the square from to pre-determine the possible directions it can bounce and then I added statements that required me to check which quadrant of the square the ball was closest to. I'm not sure if I just failed at the logic stage of this solution or if it became too much of a mammoth, but this solution worked far worse than my initial solution I was trying to implement into it.

Here is the code snippet for one direction (Ball traveling with a positive dy and dx), the other directions were done with the same logic:

```
                    else if (dy > 0 && dx > 0)
                    {
                        if (which_y_side = 2)
                        {
                            dx = -dx;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (which_x_side = 2)
                            {
                                dy = -dy;
                            }
                            else if (xdistancefromcenter < ydistancefromcenter)
                            {
                                dy = -dy;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dx = -dx;
                            }
                        }
```

Anyway, I managed to figure out two problems on my own:

- The speed of the ball can't exceed a certain range or the refresh rate of the canvas the game is ran on makes collision detection impossible to be performed as a precise calculation
- I had to add a variable to the collision detection that made sure the canvas would refresh at least once before allowing another collision, since it's possible for the game to think it has to collide with two blocks at once creating bad behaviour

Anyway, here's a working JSFiddle link to the code so you can get a better picture.

Everything relevant to the collision should be present in "CollisionDetection" -function.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/unkk5mLd/

(sorry, you will probably have to zoom the JSFiddle out a bit since the canvas is too big for the window in JSFiddle)

As far as the math goes, the ball is considered to be a square (though since it's so small, it shouldn't matter that much).

The "whichxside" and "whichyside" variables are remnants from the second implementation of the collision detection I showed an example of (code snippet #2) and I'm not currently using them in the "live version"

Comment: `which_y_side = 2` and `which_x_side = 2` in the if statements should probably be `which_y_side === 2` and `which_x_side === 2` to compare the variables instead of setting them to 2

Comment: Oh, true that. Do you have an opinion on whether or not having that type of collision detection code would be any better than the one in snippet #1 or would my #2 just add unnecessary bloat and lag to the script?